# SQL Problem on retrieving rows for further processing

Tags: mysql, sql, join, not-exists

I need to create a SQL query that can give me the row which has FIRST and SECOND CATEGORY in TABLE B but ONLY has FIRST CATEGORY row in TABLE A.
My requirement is to change TAX for that row in TABLE B to 0 (that I can do after retrieving the row and I know how to do that)

Table A

```
CITY    CATEGORY    TAX
LONDON  FIRST       20
LONDON  SECOND      30
SYDNEY  FIRST       80
PARIS   SECOND      40  
NEWYORK FIRST       30
```

Table B

```
CITY    CATEGORY    TAX
LONDON  FIRST       20
LONDON  SECOND      30
SYDNEY  FIRST       80
PARIS   SECOND      40  
NEWYORK FIRST       30
NEWYORK SECOND      90
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
CITY    CATEGORY    TAX
NEWYORK SECOND      90
```

Original Data and table for more clarity:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA(CONTRACT TEXT, ID text, CLASS TEXT, ZONE TEXT, CHARGE TEXT, FST_SC TEXT, RATE TEXT, EFFECTIVE_DATE TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(CONTRACT,ID,CLASS,ZONE,CHARGE,FST_SC,RATE,EFFECTIVE_DATE));

CREATE TABLE TABLEB( CONTRACT TEXT , ID text, CLASS TEXT, ZONE TEXT, CHARGE TEXT, FST_SC TEXT, RATE TEXT, EFFECTIVE_DATE TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(CONTRACT,ID,CLASS,ZONE,CHARGE,FST_SC,RATE,EFFECTIVE_DATE));


INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES('MS','US','UE',' ','NR','FIRST','15','09/23/2021');

INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES('MS','US','UE',' ','NR','FIRST','15','09/23/2021');
INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES('MS','US','UE',' ','NR','SECOND','15','09/23/2021');
```

DESIRED OUTPUT row is Row 2 of TABLEB - 'second' one

Comment: Please share create table and insert script for the sample data. It will be easy for everyone to provide solution.

Comment: I have edited question to represent table correctly, I just need to retrieve the desired row using SELECT statement so that I can store it into variable. Need help for SELECT statement part only... please help

Comment: Hi Aman,  Thanks for providing a solution. I have tried this one but I am facing issues due to multiple primary keys. Therefore, I am posting the orignal data and table structure for help. added details in end of question....

Comment: Have you checked the shared scripts. Scripts are throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE CITY IN 
(
    SELECT CITY FROM TableA WHERE CITY IN(
    SELECT B.CITY 
    FROM TableB  B
    GROUP BY B.CITY  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.CATEGORY)=2
) GROUP BY CITY  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CATEGORY)=1) 
AND CATEGORY='SECOND'
```